# When I pass a parameter to a class constructor, are those made available to the other functions by the same name or self is needed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Suppose I have a parameter which is passed to create an object of the class:

```
class Num1():
    def __init__(self, parameter1):
        self.param1 = parameter1
```

So now I have a class variable called `param1` which can be accessed as `self.param1` inside the class. But as we have also passed a parameter that we called `parameter1` in the constructor, can we refer to that using the variable name `parameter1` in a different method within the class?

In short, which among the two written below is correct?

```
def method1(self, parameter1)
def method1(self, self.param1)
```

when `method1` is a method of the same class?

Comment: Second one. But you don't need to pass it as an argument. You can access it with self.param1 anywhere within the class.

Comment: So the methods and variables declared inside the constructor can be accessed anywhere inside the class?

Comment: @user3656142, highly recommend you to read [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Include lines like {self.param1 = param1} in {def __init__(self, param1)}

Comment: The second one is definitely **not correct**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is correct. You do not need to add it to the arguments of the method to access it, but you do need to use `self` when referring to it.

This is the correct way:

```
def method3(self):
    print(self.param1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Within the class, the parameter is accessible as self.param1. But you should not add it to the methods' signatures.

So the answer is:

```
def method1(self):
    print(self.param1)
```